# How to join queries in MySQL to find WordPress posts based on distance calculation and Google Geocoding?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, subquery, inner-join, geocoding

I am trying to prepare a query for finding places based on user's current location using WordPress table structure.

I am developing this application in WordPress.

I created a custom post type called store. When a store is added from the admin, I am able to find its `lat/lng` values using Geocoding and storing them in `wp_postmeta` table against two meta keys `store_lat` and `store_lng` while the basic information is getting stored in `wp_posts` table.

I want to get Stores from wp_posts table by filtering the records in wp_postmeta table using the distance between two points, one of these being user's current location.

I built the following query get lat/lng values in one row for each post_id from wp_postmeta table which is coming up fine:

```
SELECT a.post_id, a.meta_value as lat, b.meta_value as lng
FROM
wp_postmeta as a, 
wp_postmeta as b

WHERE a.meta_key = "store_lat"
AND b.meta_key= "store_lng"
AND a.post_id = b.post_id
```

I also got the query to find "nearest locations" based on current location of the user:

```
SELECT id, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(22) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(88) ) + sin( radians(22) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM *** HAVING distance < 1 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

But I cannot join these two queries to find our stores. I am not been able to figure out what to put in place of `***` and get the desired stores from wp_posts table.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like this:

```
SELECT
store.post_id       AS store_id,
6371 * 2 *  ASIN
                (
                    SQRT
                    (
                        POWER(SIN((store.lat - ABS(user.lat)) * PI()/180 / 2),2)
                        + COS(store.lat * PI()/180) * COS(ABS(user.lat) * PI()/180) * POWER(SIN((store.lng - user.lng) * PI()/180 / 2), 2)
                    )
                )       AS distance                                      
FROM    (SELECT 0.5 AS lat,
                1       AS lng
    ) AS user,
    (SELECT
        a.post_id,
        a.meta_value    AS lat,
        b.meta_value    AS lng
    FROM    wp_postmeta AS a,
            wp_postmeta AS b
    WHERE   a.meta_key = "store_lat" AND
            b.meta_key = "store_lng" AND
            a.post_id = b.post_id
    ) AS store                                                            
ORDER BY distance ASC                                                     
LIMIT 0,20
```

Of course you can hand over the user's location differently and also apply your maximum distance (e.g. HAVING distance < 1).

I changed the distance function to something I found [here](https://gist.github.com/Usse/4086343)